# CSS text align not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've got a sicky footer with

```
display:table-row;
```

the text is centered.

I would like to have copyrights aligned to the left and social media aligned to the right. I did this:

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="container">
<span id="copyright">Copyright 2015</span>
<span id="socials">facebook</span>
</div>
</div>
```

the css

```
#footer {
display: table-row;
height: 10px;
}

#copyright { text-align: left;}
#socials { text-align: right;}
```

It doesn't seem to be aligned. please help. thanks

Comment: this? https://jsbin.com/cakogorito/edit?html,output

Comment: text-align is applied to the parent to align the parent's inline element content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use float to achieve this.

```
#copyright { float: left; }
#socials { float: right; }
```

Reason is, span by default is a `display: inline`. This means it won't fill the whole div so you'll end up seeing both next to each other.

Your other "issue" is that the div has `display:table-row` - any reason for this? If you have a parent div for that footer, using `display:table`, it should work as is. If not, you will need to remove the `display:table-row`

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqf91p8q/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I did not realize you are using `display: table-row;` on the footer. This is what is causing your first problem. You need to remove this, set the width to 100% and then do the floats like so:

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
}

#copyright {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#socials {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/422vj1e0/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  #footer {
display: table-row;
height: 10px;
}

#copyright {float:left;}
#socials {float: right;}
</style>
<div id="footer">
<div id="container">
<span id="copyright">Copyright 2015</span>
<span id="socials">facebook</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
height: 10px;
}

#copyright { float: left;}
#socials { float: right;}
```

Please try this code

Answer (score 0):

we use 'display:table-row;' when we have `display:table;` in parent div.  div is by default `display:block` so you do not need to write the property for it.

you should try floating for #copyright and #socials instead of text-align.

write this CSS

```
 #footer {
    height: 10px;
    }

    #copyright {  float: left;}
    #socials { float: right;}
```

Comment: Would you consider adding a little more explanation to your answer to possibly make it more useful?